# 10 years of Magento on StackExchage

Tags: discussion

It gives me great pleasure to write this here as our favorite StackExchange website just turned 10 years old.

[image]

It was a long journey, but a fun one.
In the last 10 years we've build a great community, we shared here our problems and frustration but also our knowledge and our great ideas. Thank you all for being part of it.

Now let's remember what got us here.

It all started with a proposal on area51.stackexchange.com at the end of 2012 by our favorite person in the whole world, [Ben Marks](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/5/benmarks).
The private beta started on January 22nd 2013 and one week later came the public beta.
In August 2015 magento.stackexchange.com graduated and became a fully functioning stackexchange website with the help of all of us.

In the last 10 years we gathered up some impressive numbers (at the time of writing this):

- 83764 users
- 111642 questions
- 140965 answers
- 364180 comments
- 417538 upvotes
- 31762 downvotes
- 225419 badges earned

  - 4000 gold
  - 35147 silver
  - 186272 bronze
- **∞ knowledge shared**

First question ever posted: [Magento Authorize.net - Authorize and Capture vs. Authorize Only](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1/magento-authorize-net-authorize-and-capture-vs-authorize-only)

First answer ever posted: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6

Thank you all again for the contributions.

Comment: Congratulations to you all!

Comment: Ten years, and each has been better than the last. Thanks for providing such a nice platform where we can get the solution and learn something new. Congratulations to all.

Comment: Congratulations  all

Comment: Congratulations @all

Comment: Congratulations and glad to be part of this community

Comment: Congratulations @all! It's a long journey!

Comment: Congratulations everyone !

Comment: Congratulations all :)

Comment: Congratulations to you All !!!

Comment: Nice round number of gold badges.